How can I decrypt voice data received from Discord?
I'm trying to decrypt the voice data received from Discord that uses xsalsa20_poly1305 encryption mode. My goal would be to record & use audio to chat with AI.
What could I do wrong? Thanks for any help!
My code:
async def record_audio(udp_socket, ssrc, secret_key):
    box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(bytes(secret_key)) # TODO: Fix decryption xsalsa20_poly1305
    print("Listening for audio data...")

    try:
        response, _ = udp_socket.recvfrom(74)
        print(f"Received response: {response}")
        # Process the response...
    except socket.timeout:
        print("IP discovery timeout")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error during IP discovery: {e}")
        return None, None

    while True:
        print("Waiting for audio data...")
        try:
            ready, _, _ = select.select([udp_socket], [], [], 5.0)
            if udp_socket in ready:
                data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(65536)  # Adjust buffer size as necessary
                print(f"Received {len(data)} bytes from {addr}: {data.hex()}")

                if len(data) > 12:

                    # Extract the RTP header
                    header = data[:12]

                    # Construct the nonce
                    nonce = header + b'\x00' * 12

                    print(f"Nonce: {len(nonce)} bytes")

                    # Get the encrypted audio data
                    encrypted = data[12:]

                    print(f"Encrypted audio data: {len(encrypted)} bytes")


                    #The rest of the data is the encrypted audio data (Should be 48 - 24 = 24 bytes)


                    #nonce  = data[:12]

                    #print(f"Nonce: {nonce}")

                    #if len(nonce) < 12:
                    #    nonce.ljust(24, b'\x00')
                    #remaining 12 bytes can be zeros or another fixed pattern
                    #nonce = nonce_part + bytes(12)
                    #copy the RTP header to get the nonce
                    #nonce = bytearray(24)
                    #nonce[:12] = data[:12]#data[:12]

                    #get the encrypted audio data
                    #encrypted = data[12:]
                    print(f"Encrypted audio data: {bytes(encrypted)}")
                    try:
                        audio_data = box.decrypt(bytes(data), bytes(nonce))
                        print("Received audio data")
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Decryption error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error receiving audio data: {e}")
            break

Edit: The secret key is passed directly from the opcode 4 object received from Discord.
Output:
Waiting for audio data...
Received 48 bytes from ('66.22.243.22', 50023): 81c9000700013adfaf6439133ca81bfcd2b35eb743f2a4af0165e3cf0517d8efee5dae36ec6653c88a2d625064af33d6
Nonce: 24 bytes
Nonce: b'\x81\xc9\x00\x07\x00\x01:\xdf\xafd9\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Encrypted audio data: 36 bytes
Encrypted audio data: b'<\xa8\x1b\xfc\xd2\xb3^\xb7C\xf2\xa4\xaf\x01e\xe3\xcf\x05\x17\xd8\xef\xee]\xae6\xecfS\xc8\x8a-bPd\xaf3\xd6'
Decryption error: Decryption failed. Ciphertext failed verification

I can't include my Discord token for security reasons but there are some testing data:
{'op': 4, 'd': {'video_codec': 'H264', 'secure_frames_version': 0, 'secret_key': [20, 115, 239, 10, 206, 186, 11, 248, 52, 47, 193, 69, 170, 89, 146, 187, 215, 181, 4, 177, 173, 132, 50, 212, 141, 194, 52, 217, 219, 17, 111, 5], 'mode': 'xsalsa20_poly1305', 'media_session_id': '77d90ef5c4aa124c0dcd6d39bbe88f9f', 'audio_codec': 'opus'}}
Udp socket:  <socket.socket fd=604, family=2, type=2, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 56866)>
SSRC:  112825
Secret key:  [20, 115, 239, 10, 206, 186, 11, 248, 52, 47, 193, 69, 170, 89, 146, 187, 215, 181, 4, 177, 173, 132, 50, 212, 141, 194, 52, 217, 219, 17, 111, 5]
Received data: b'\x81\xc9\x00\x07\x00\x00gIZ.Y\xaf\xf8\x94\xb4a}?gm"\xc6R\x02\\\x13\xaf>@\xf0\xe8\xca\xd0\x90\xf3\x16\x89h\x14\x81s\xa0\x00\xf3$v\x99|'

Everything in bytearrays:
Data: [129, 201, 0, 7, 0, 1, 87, 149, 132, 179, 156, 19, 161, 42, 79, 112, 160, 142, 72, 43, 68, 43, 225, 201, 66, 97, 38, 88, 120, 123, 192, 102, 18, 163, 126, 210, 96, 21, 113, 212, 66, 63, 102, 7, 123, 24, 141, 1]
RTP header: [129, 201, 0, 7, 0, 1, 87, 149, 132, 179, 156, 19]
Nonce: [129, 201, 0, 7, 0, 1, 87, 149, 132, 179, 156, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Voice data: [161, 42, 79, 112, 160, 142, 72, 43, 68, 43, 225, 201, 66, 97, 38, 88, 120, 123, 192, 102, 18, 163, 126, 210, 96, 21, 113, 212, 66, 63, 102, 7, 123, 24, 141, 1]


XSalsa20 applies a 24 bytes nonce, Discord uses the RTP header as nonce in xsalsa20_poly1305 mode. Why do you take only half and use 0x00 values for the remainder? Post sample data for a repro if possible.

@Topaco I have tried that + edited my question but still wrong...

Can you post complete test data for a repro?

@Topaco Yeah, I have now added the ones to the question you may need.

I can't decrypt this test data even with a second Libsodium library (assuming that the first 12 bytes are the nonce (with 0x00 padding to 24 bytes), or that the first 24 bytes are the nonce). The data seems to be corrupt or is not what you think it is.

Yep, it is possible because I get the same data over and over again, maybe it is just silence or something like that. The data comes from Discord thats for sure

Decryption with XSalsa20_Poly1305 is not tricky: key, nonce, ciphertext. So if it doesn't work with two independent libraries, the only conclusion is that it's because of the data. The data does not have to be corrupt, but your mapping may be wrong.

@Topaco I have converted everything to bytearray and added it to the question as well. It seems correct but doesn't work... Maybe this is an issue with Python itself because I have experienced differences with SHA validation between Python and JS as well

So I have found the solution. When no one is in the voice channel, Discord seemingly sends a lot of rubbish data followed by five packages of silence (0xF8, 0xFF, 0xFE) then rubbish, undecryptable data again. In order to receive some XSalsa20_Poly1305 compatible bytes, someone has to be in the voice channel and must speak or make any sound. I initially didn't test it while in voice because I thought that silence will be in the same format as voice and if I decrypt it, I'll be good to go...
By the way, thanks Topaco for pointing out some key issues with my implementation and testing stuff as well!
